# Как сделать всплывающие окно при наведении?

Tags: css

Помогите разобраться языковым меню нужно что бы при наведении мыши на языковое меню появлялось языковая панель. Вот накидал код  но оно не работает в чем проблема пожалуйста помогите разобраться.

```css
.hideNetworkBar {
    display: none;
}

.networkBar {
    background: #000000;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: normal;
    position: relative;
}

.networkListContent {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
}

.networkSticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 50;
}

.networkStickyBg,
.networkStickyBg.light {
    background: #ffffff;
}

.networkListContent li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    vertical-align: top;
}

.networkListContent .networkTab {
    color: #BBBBBB;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px 24px;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-bold: normal;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.networkListContent>li>.networkTab {
    height: 22px;
}

.networkListContent .languageDropdown>.networkTab {
    min-width: 75px;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
   position: relative;
    display: inline-block; 
}

.networkListContent .networkTab img {
    width: 16px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.networkListContent .networkTab.current {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: default;
}

.networkListContent .networkTab.current:hover {
    background: transparent;
}

.networkListContent .downArrow>.networkTab:after,
.networkListContent .upArrow>.networkTab:after,
.networkListContent .leftArrow>.networkTab:after,
.networkListContent .rightArrow>.networkTab:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
}

.networkListContent .downArrow.active.rotateArrow>.networkTab:after,
.networkListContent .upArrow.active.rotateArrow>.networkTab:after,
.networkListContent .leftArrow.active.rotateArrow>.networkTab:after,
.networkListContent .rightArrow.active.rotateArrow>.networkTab:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.networkListContent .downArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.networkListContent .upArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.networkListContent .leftArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.networkListContent .rightArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.networkListContent .downArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
}

.networkListContent .leftArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-right-color: #ffffff;
}

.networkListContent .rightArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
}

.networkListContent .upArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}

.networkListContent .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 50;
    right: 0;
    width: 75px;
    background: #333333;
}

.networkListContent .wide .dropdown {
    width: 150px;
}

.networkListContent .dropdown.subDropdown {
    left: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #282828;
}

.networkListContent .dropdown.hide {
    display: none;
}

.networkListContent .dropdown li {
    display: block;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.networkListContent .dropdown li .networkTab {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.networkListContent>li>.networkTab:hover,
.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent>.dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab,
.networkListContent>.dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #333333;
}

.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent>li:not(.active)>.networkTab:hover {
    color: #BBBBBB;
    background: transparent;
}

.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent>li>.networkTab.current:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.networkListContent .dropdown .dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab,
.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent .dropdown .dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab,
.networkListContent .dropdown>li .networkTab:hover {
    background: #282828;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent .dropdown>li .networkTab:hover {
    color: #BBBBBB;
    background: transparent;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .networkListContent .networkTab {
        padding: 5px 18.3px;
    }
    .networkListContent .languageDropdown>.networkTab {
        min-width: 63px;
    }
    .networkListContent .dropdown {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .networkListContent .dropdown.subDropdown {
        left: 0;
        bottom: auto;
        top: 32px;
    }
    .networkListContent .downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        margin-left: 5px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        top: 4px;
    }
    .networkListContent .downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-left: 3px solid transparent;
        border-right: 3px solid transparent;
        border-top: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    .networkListContent .upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-left: 3px solid transparent;
        border-right: 3px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
        border-top: none;
    }
    .networkListContent .leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-top: 3px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
        border-right: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
        border-left: none;
    }
    .networkListContent .rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-top: 3px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
        border-right: none;
    }
    .networkListContent .downArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-top-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .networkListContent .leftArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-right-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .networkListContent .rightArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-left-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .networkListContent .upArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .networkListContent .downArrow.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrowTablet.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrowTablet.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrowTablet.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrowTablet.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    .networkListContent .downArrow.active.rotateArrow.disableRotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.active.rotateArrow.disableRotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.active.rotateArrow.disableRotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.active.rotateArrow.disableRotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    .networkListContent .noArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .networkListContent .networkTab {
        padding: 5px 8.8px;
    }
    .networkListContent .languageDropdown>.networkTab {
        min-width: 44px;
    }
}

.networkBar.light {
    background: #fff;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .networkTab {
    color: #474747;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .dropdown {
    background: #dbdbdb;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .dropdown .dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab,
.networkBar.light.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent .dropdown .dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab,
.networkBar.light .networkListContent .dropdown>li .networkTab:hover {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    color: #747474;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .dropdown.subDropdown {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    color: #747474;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .networkTab.current {
    color: #747474;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .networkTab.current:hover {
    background: transparent;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent>li>.networkTab:hover,
.networkBar.light.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent>.dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab,
.networkBar.light .networkListContent>.dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab {
    color: #747474;
    background: #dbdbdb;
}

.networkBar.light.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent .dropdown>li.dropdownTrigger:not(.active) .networkTab:hover {
    color: #474747;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-top-color: #474747;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-bottom-color: #474747;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-right-color: #474747;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-left-color: #474747;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-top-color: #747474;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-right-color: #747474;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-left-color: #747474;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-bottom-color: #747474;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-left-color: transparent;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-top-color: #474747;
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-left-color: transparent;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-bottom-color: #474747;
        border-top-color: none;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        border-right-color: #474747;
        border-left: none;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        border-left-color: #474747;
        border-right: none;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-top-color: #747474;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-right-color: #747474;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-left-color: #747474;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-bottom-color: #747474;
    }
    .networkBar.light.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent .dropdown>li .networkTab:hover,
    .networkBar.light.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent>li:not(.active)>.networkTab:hover {
        background: transparent;
        color: #474747;
    }
    .networkBar.light.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent>li>.networkTab.current:hover {
        color: #747474;
    }
}

.networkBar {
    width: 1323px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1349px) {
    .networkBar {
        width: 991px;
    }
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown hide {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown hide a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown hide a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.networkListContent .languageDropdown>.networkTab:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.networkListContent .languageDropdown>.networkTab:hover .networkTab {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<div id="js-networkBar" class="networkBar">
   <ul class="networkListContent">
      <li data-id="1" class="alpha"><span class="networkTab current">Главная</span></li>
      <li data-id="2"><a class="networkTab" href="">Контакты</a></li>
      <li data-id="3"><a class="networkTab" href="">Знакомства</a></li>
      <li data-id="4"><a class="networkTab" href="">Форум</a></li>
      <li data-id="5"><a class="networkTab" href="">Чат</a></li>
      <li class="dropdownTrigger wide" data-id="6">
         <span class="networkTab">Игры</span>       
      <li data-id="7"><a class="networkTab" href="">Товары &amp; Услуги</a></li>
      <li class="dropdownTrigger downArrow rotateArrow languageDropdown omega" data-id="8">
         <span class="networkTab">ru</span>
         <ul class="dropdown hide">
            <li data-id="91" data-lang="de" class="alpha"><a class="networkTab" href="">Deutsch</a></li>
            <li data-id="92" data-lang="fr"><a class="networkTab" href="">Français</a></li>
            <li data-id="93" data-lang="es"><a class="networkTab" href="">Español</a></li>
            <li data-id="94" data-lang="it"><a class="networkTab" href="">Italiano</a></li>
            <li data-id="95" data-lang="pt"><a class="networkTab" href="">Português</a></li>
            <li data-id="96" data-lang="pl"><a class="networkTab" href="">Polski</a></li>
            <li data-id="97" data-lang="en"><a class="networkTab" href="">English</a></li>
            <li data-id="98" data-lang="jp"><a class="networkTab" href="">日本語</a></li>
            <li data-id="99" data-lang="nl"><a class="networkTab" href="">Dutch</a></li>
            <li data-id="991" data-lang="cz"><a class="networkTab" href="">Czech</a></li>
            <li data-id="992" data-lang="cn" class="omega"><a class="networkTab" href="">中文(简体)</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hideNetworkBar {
    display: none;
}

.networkBar {
    background: #000000;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: normal;
    position: relative;
}

.networkListContent {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
}

.networkSticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 50;
}

.networkStickyBg,
.networkStickyBg.light {
    background: #ffffff;
}

.networkListContent li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    vertical-align: top;
}

.networkListContent .networkTab {
    color: #BBBBBB;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px 24px;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-bold: normal;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.networkListContent>li>.networkTab {
    height: 22px;
}

.networkListContent .languageDropdown>.networkTab {
    min-width: 75px;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
   position: relative;
    display: inline-block; 
}

.networkListContent .networkTab img {
    width: 16px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.networkListContent .networkTab.current {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: default;
}

.networkListContent .networkTab.current:hover {
    background: transparent;
}

.networkListContent .downArrow>.networkTab:after,
.networkListContent .upArrow>.networkTab:after,
.networkListContent .leftArrow>.networkTab:after,
.networkListContent .rightArrow>.networkTab:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
}

.networkListContent .downArrow.active.rotateArrow>.networkTab:after,
.networkListContent .upArrow.active.rotateArrow>.networkTab:after,
.networkListContent .leftArrow.active.rotateArrow>.networkTab:after,
.networkListContent .rightArrow.active.rotateArrow>.networkTab:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.networkListContent .downArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.networkListContent .upArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.networkListContent .leftArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.networkListContent .rightArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.networkListContent .downArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
}

.networkListContent .leftArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-right-color: #ffffff;
}

.networkListContent .rightArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
}

.networkListContent .upArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}

.networkListContent .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 50;
    right: 0;
    width: 75px;
    background: #333333;
}

.networkListContent .wide .dropdown {
    width: 150px;
}

.networkListContent .dropdown.subDropdown {
    left: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #282828;
}

.networkListContent .dropdown.hide {
    display: none;
}

.networkListContent .dropdown li {
    display: block;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.networkListContent .dropdown li .networkTab {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.networkListContent>li>.networkTab:hover,
.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent>.dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab,
.networkListContent>.dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #333333;
}

.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent>li:not(.active)>.networkTab:hover {
    color: #BBBBBB;
    background: transparent;
}

.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent>li>.networkTab.current:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.networkListContent .dropdown .dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab,
.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent .dropdown .dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab,
.networkListContent .dropdown>li .networkTab:hover {
    background: #282828;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent .dropdown>li .networkTab:hover {
    color: #BBBBBB;
    background: transparent;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .networkListContent .networkTab {
        padding: 5px 18.3px;
    }
    .networkListContent .languageDropdown>.networkTab {
        min-width: 63px;
    }
    .networkListContent .dropdown {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .networkListContent .dropdown.subDropdown {
        left: 0;
        bottom: auto;
        top: 32px;
    }
    .networkListContent .downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        margin-left: 5px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        top: 4px;
    }
    .networkListContent .downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-left: 3px solid transparent;
        border-right: 3px solid transparent;
        border-top: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    .networkListContent .upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-left: 3px solid transparent;
        border-right: 3px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
        border-top: none;
    }
    .networkListContent .leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-top: 3px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
        border-right: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
        border-left: none;
    }
    .networkListContent .rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-top: 3px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid #BBBBBB;
        border-right: none;
    }
    .networkListContent .downArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-top-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .networkListContent .leftArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-right-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .networkListContent .rightArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-left-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .networkListContent .upArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .networkListContent .downArrow.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .downArrowTablet.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrowTablet.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrowTablet.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrowTablet.active.rotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    .networkListContent .downArrow.active.rotateArrow.disableRotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .upArrow.active.rotateArrow.disableRotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .leftArrow.active.rotateArrow.disableRotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkListContent .rightArrow.active.rotateArrow.disableRotateArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    .networkListContent .noArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .networkListContent .networkTab {
        padding: 5px 8.8px;
    }
    .networkListContent .languageDropdown>.networkTab {
        min-width: 44px;
    }
}

.networkBar.light {
    background: #fff;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .networkTab {
    color: #474747;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .dropdown {
    background: #dbdbdb;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .dropdown .dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab,
.networkBar.light.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent .dropdown .dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab,
.networkBar.light .networkListContent .dropdown>li .networkTab:hover {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    color: #747474;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .dropdown.subDropdown {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    color: #747474;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .networkTab.current {
    color: #747474;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .networkTab.current:hover {
    background: transparent;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent>li>.networkTab:hover,
.networkBar.light.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent>.dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab,
.networkBar.light .networkListContent>.dropdownTrigger.active>.networkTab {
    color: #747474;
    background: #dbdbdb;
}

.networkBar.light.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent .dropdown>li.dropdownTrigger:not(.active) .networkTab:hover {
    color: #474747;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-top-color: #474747;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-bottom-color: #474747;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-right-color: #474747;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrow>.networkTab:after {
    border-left-color: #474747;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-top-color: #747474;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-right-color: #747474;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-left-color: #747474;
}

.networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrow.active>.networkTab:after {
    border-bottom-color: #747474;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrow.downArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-left-color: transparent;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-top-color: #474747;
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrow.upArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-left-color: transparent;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-bottom-color: #474747;
        border-top-color: none;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrow.leftArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        border-right-color: #474747;
        border-left: none;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after,
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrow.rightArrowTablet>.networkTab:after {
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        border-left-color: #474747;
        border-right: none;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .downArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-top-color: #747474;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .leftArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-right-color: #747474;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .rightArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-left-color: #747474;
    }
    .networkBar.light .networkListContent .upArrowTablet.active>.networkTab:after {
        border-bottom-color: #747474;
    }
    .networkBar.light.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent .dropdown>li .networkTab:hover,
    .networkBar.light.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent>li:not(.active)>.networkTab:hover {
        background: transparent;
        color: #474747;
    }
    .networkBar.light.tabletNetworkBar .networkListContent>li>.networkTab.current:hover {
        color: #747474;
    }
}

.networkBar {
    width: 1323px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1349px) {
    .networkBar {
        width: 991px;
    }
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.languageDropdown:hover > .dropdown{
      display: block;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown hide a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.networkListContent .languageDropdown>.networkTab:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.networkListContent .languageDropdown>.networkTab:hover .networkTab {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<div id="js-networkBar" class="networkBar">
   <ul class="networkListContent">
      <li data-id="1" class="alpha"><span class="networkTab current">Главная</span></li>
      <li data-id="2"><a class="networkTab" href="">Контакты</a></li>
      <li data-id="3"><a class="networkTab" href="">Знакомства</a></li>
      <li data-id="4"><a class="networkTab" href="">Форум</a></li>
      <li data-id="5"><a class="networkTab" href="">Чат</a></li>
      <li class="dropdownTrigger wide" data-id="6">
         <span class="networkTab">Игры</span>       
      <li data-id="7"><a class="networkTab" href="">Товары &amp; Услуги</a></li>
      <li class="dropdownTrigger downArrow rotateArrow languageDropdown omega" data-id="8">
         <span class="networkTab">ru</span>
         <ul class="dropdown">
            <li data-id="91" data-lang="de" class="alpha"><a class="networkTab" href="">Deutsch</a></li>
            <li data-id="92" data-lang="fr"><a class="networkTab" href="">Français</a></li>
            <li data-id="93" data-lang="es"><a class="networkTab" href="">Español</a></li>
            <li data-id="94" data-lang="it"><a class="networkTab" href="">Italiano</a></li>
            <li data-id="95" data-lang="pt"><a class="networkTab" href="">Português</a></li>
            <li data-id="96" data-lang="pl"><a class="networkTab" href="">Polski</a></li>
            <li data-id="97" data-lang="en"><a class="networkTab" href="">English</a></li>
            <li data-id="98" data-lang="jp"><a class="networkTab" href="">日本語</a></li>
            <li data-id="99" data-lang="nl"><a class="networkTab" href="">Dutch</a></li>
            <li data-id="991" data-lang="cz"><a class="networkTab" href="">Czech</a></li>
            <li data-id="992" data-lang="cn" class="omega"><a class="networkTab" href="">中文(简体)</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```